# Not able to find winutils.exe for hadoop 2.6.0 for 32 bit windows

Tags: windows, hadoop

I am looking for winutils.exe for 32-bit windows and hadoop.dll for hadoop 2.6.0 version.

During the execution of Map reduce example first I got the error telling
ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path

So I downloaded a version and update the bin folder again executing the same command I am getting error like

```
ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable C:\hadoop-2.6.0\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:355)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:363)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the compiled Hadoop 2.7.1 32 bit native Windows package from my blog.

[Apache Hadoop 2.7.1 Native Windows 32 Bit Binaries](http://prowessteja.blogspot.in/2015/10/apache-hadoop-271-native-windows-32-bit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Titus Barik has put together a downloadable archive of Hadoop 2.6 with the Windows utilities already compiled.

http://www.barik.net/archive/2015/01/19/172716/

Comment: These appear to all be 64 bit. The question is asking for 32-bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find 32-bit winutils.exe at below location.

https://launchpad.net/winutils/+download

Comment: page not found... -1