# Apache Spark installation on windows 7 32 bit

Tags: hadoop, windows-7, apache-spark, installation, 32-bit

I have just began studying `apache spark`. First thing which i did was i tried to install `spark` on my machine. I downloaded the pre built spark 1.5.2 with `hadoop 2.6`. When i ran `spark shell` i got following erros

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at     org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>    (ClientWrapper.scala:171)
    at     org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala    :163)
        at     org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:168)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
    at <init>(<console>:20)
    at .<init>(<console>:24)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
```

I searched for this error and got that i have to download winutils.exe which i did, I set the path `HADOOP_HOME = "c:\Hadoop"` and then ran the command

```
C:\Hadoop\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 /tmp/hive
```

but i got following error

```
This version of C:\Hadoop\bin\winutils.exe is not compatible with the version of
 Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether
 you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contac
t the software publisher.
```

I tried to search 32 bit version of winutils.exe but i couldnt get it.. Please help me with this installation. 
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following links may be helpful.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9922

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11784

[Not able to find winutils.exe for hadoop 2.6.0 for 32 bit windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410983/not-able-to-find-winutils-exe-for-hadoop-2-6-0-for-32-bit-windows)

Comment: [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9922] This has the patch to make it work for 32 bit.